# mongoose limit & nin not working properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am trying to limit the number of records returned in a query:

```
Property.find(searchParams).nin('_id', prop_ids).limit(5).exec(function(err, properties) {
```

when the first call comes in, i get 5 records back. then i make a second call and pass in an array of ids (prop_ids). This array has all of the ids that were records that were returned in the first call... in this case i get no records back. I have a total of 7 records in my database, so the second call should return 2 records. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Could you give more complete code?

Answer (score -2):

I think mongoose might apply the limit before the `nin` query is applied so you will always just get those five. If it's a type of pagination you want to perform where you get 5 objects and then get 5 others, you can use the option skip instead:

```
var SKIP = ... // 0, 5, 10...
Property.find(searchParams, null, {
    skip: SKIP,
    limit: 5,
}, function(err, properties) {

})
```

This is what I took from your question, maybe you had something other in mind with the `nin` call?

Comment: The limit is applied to the query with all predicates, not before the `$nin`.